# Check Expiry by comparing date store and current date MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying out a linq query check expiry by comparing a saved date and current date in mvc3 controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult _leftHomeAd()
    {    var LhAd = db.Adverts
         .Where(u => u.ACatId ==1)
         .Where(u => u.OffDate <= DateTime.Now.Day);
          return PartialView(LhAd);
```

And I get the error that I cannot use <= for system date.  Can someone point me in the right direction so that my query can retrieve only adverts that have not expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `DateTime.Now.Day`?  Change it:

```
.Where(u => u.OffDate <= DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change from

```
DateTime.Now.Day
```

to

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

because `Day` is `int`, not `DateTime`